# Selecting more columns than necessary for insert for use in RETURNING statement

Tags: postgresql, sql-insert, bulkinsert, sql-returning

To illustrate, here are some tables in Postgres 9.6:

```
people
 id | name 
----+------
  1 | a
  2 | b
  3 | c
  4 | d

groups
 id | name 
----+-------
 10 | xxx
 20 | yyy
 30 | zzz

people_in_group
person_id | group_id
----------+-------
1         | 10
2         | 10
```

I would like to insert multiple values in people_in_group, and have the group names returned to me. I already have the person_id (2). The following works, but does not return the name.

```
INSERT INTO people_in_group(person_id, group_id) 
  SELECT '2' AS person_id, id as group_id FROM groups 
  WHERE name IN ('xxx', 'yyy', 'not there') 
  ON CONFLICT DO NOTHING 
  RETURNING *;
```

If I add `name` to the `SELECT` clause, I'll get `INSERT has more expressions than target columns`. Is there any way to have `name` from the groups table returned to me (via the `RETURNING` clause)? I know I pass in the group names, but the above query would fail to insert for 'xxx' (duplicate key), and 'not there' (no such group), so it would only return 'yyy'. Ideally, I'd like to be able to know why certain `INSERTs` failed, but I'll take what I can get.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
with i as (
    insert into people_in_group(person_id, group_id) 
    select '2' as person_id, id as group_id
    from groups 
    where name in ('xxx', 'yyy', 'not there') 
    on conflict do nothing 
    returning *
)
select i.person_id, i.group_id, g.name
from i inner join groups g on g.id = i.group_id
```